# iOS app store In App Purchase rules flexibility?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

We currently have an app in the itunnes Appstore which features in-app-purchase for Apple users as well as login for paying users **through our own system**. Now this app has existed for a while so apparently Apple is OK with it. Maybe because those who have paid through our system are public schools and municipalities... I frankly don't know since their guidelines state:

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app purchase. Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than IAP.

And this worries me because:

> If you attempt to cheat the system (for example, by trying to trick the review process, steal user data, copy another developer's work, or manipulate ratings) your apps will be removed from the store and you will be expelled from the Developer Program.

Now recently we updated the app with a new feature which was unavailable for the in-app-purchase customers but enabled for our personal customers*. Again Apple is fine with it but I worry that is only because they don't know... I don't dare ask Apple directly as I might end up getting our app pulled etc. so that is why I ask my question here:

If Apple are fine with the old setup that had all features available for in-app-purchase customers could this new added feature which only works for our customers and not Apple in-app-purchase users be a major issue? How flexible is Apple on this area in everyone else experience?

'* (This is a dumb setup I know, but the problem is our services is locked to only be used for our personal customers and this new feature requires our services.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @i_am_jorf I get that and I was afraid of that. But it is really hard to find any resources on this topic. Which is why I hopped stackoverflow though it would be relevant enough.